Duende Identity server upgrade from 6.3 to 7 issues with Entity Framework migrations
I am currently in process to upgrade duende identity server 6.3 to latest version(7). I am following the steps in this guide https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v7/upgrades/v6.3_to_v7.0/
But when I am trying to run the migration commands
dotnet ef migrations add Update_DuendeIdentityServer_v7_0 -c ConfigurationDbContext -o Migrations/ConfigurationDb

dotnet ef migrations add Update_DuendeIdentityServer_v7_0 -c PersistedGrantDbContext -o Migrations/PersistedGrantDb

I am getting the following error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'ConfigurationDbContext'. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.DbContexts.ConfigurationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.DbContexts.ConfigurationDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728


This is working solution and builds are happening and working as expected in version 6.3 so there should not be any issues with the current code.
I am lost at this point, any assistance would be appreciated.

Did you try as admin ?

I did that's the 1st thing I tried. No luck there.
